# Adding "infinite" values in a Do While

Tags: c#, loops

```
do
{
    int nextUserCard = kartendeck.GetARandomCard();
    userDecision = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("You have: " + kartendeck.ReturnCardName(nextUserCard) + " V:" + kartendeck.ReturnCardValue(nextUserCard));
    Console.WriteLine(GET THE ADDED CARD VALUE)
    Console.WriteLine("Pick? y/n");
} while (userDecision != "n");
```

I have this console do while loop and I want to add the values(int) of kartendeck.ReturnCardValue(nextUserCard) until the user decides to leave.

Whats the best method to safe and add the values? I don't expect complete code, but highly appreciate some help.

Comment: Just use a `List<int>` and add the return to this list

Comment: what is the problem? it looks almost like it works. you can only extract methods out to make it beter structured.

Comment: Do you want to sum the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<T>` is the structure you need :

```
List<int> data = new List<int>();

do
{
    int nextUserCard = kartendeck.GetARandomCard();
    data.Add(nextUserCard)
    userDecision = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("You have: " + kartendeck.ReturnCardName(nextUserCard) + " V:" + kartendeck.ReturnCardValue(nextUserCard));
    Console.WriteLine(GET THE ADDED CARD VALUE)
    Console.WriteLine("Pick? y/n");
} while (userDecision != "n");

// here you can access data and loop through it or do whatever.
// example: int sum = data.Sum();
// example :
// for(int value in data)
// {
//    Console.WriteLine(value);
// }
```

Comment: List<int> data = new List<int>(); data.Add(kartendeck.ReturnCardValue(nextUserCard));Console.WriteLine(data.Sum()); - Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the previously selected values somewhere. There are two possible approaches to this.

1. Maintain a running total by adding to an Int variable (or an Int64, if int overflow is a concern)
2. Maintain a list of previously selected values, and only calculate the result when the user requests it